# How to speed up writing points to InfluxDB?

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, rust, influxdb

I'm writing points (60k per batch) to InfluxDB.

Point contains time (i64) and value (f64).

It looks like.

```
use influx_db_client::{
    Client, Point, Points, Value, Precision
};
use tokio;

fn main() {
    let client = Client::new(Url::parse("http://localhost:8086").expect("Cannot parse url"), "test");

    let data: Vec<Point> = get_data();

    tokio::runtime::Runtime::new().unwrap().block_on(async move { 
        for chunk in data.chunks(60000) {
            let points = Points::create_new(chunk.to_vec());
            client.write_points(points, Some(Precision::Milliseconds), None).await.expect("Cannot write points");   
        }
    });
}
```

It works and it takes 6 seconds but I think it may be faster.
I tried to use threadpool but it doesn't work because I can't create a lot of clients.

```
use influx_db_client::{
    Client, Point, Points, Value, Precision
};
use tokio;
use threadpool::ThreadPool;

fn main() {
    let n_workers = 4;
    let data: Vec<Point> = get_data();
    let pool = ThreadPool::new(n_workers);
    for chunk in data.chunks(60000) {
        let points = Points::create_new(chunk.to_vec());
        pool.execute(move || {
            tokio::runtime::Runtime::new().unwrap().block_on(async move { 
                let client = Client::new(Url::parse("http://localhost:8086").expect("Cannot parse url"), "test");
                client.write_points(points, Some(Precision::Milliseconds), None).await.expect("Cannot write points");
            });
        });
    }
}
```

So I don't know how to execute it faster.

Can I use asynchronous?
Probably you know some optimization tricks?

`data` contains 1'400'000 points (they are quickly created, 1.3 s, get_data() - 0.627 s, chunk loop (without calling client.write_points) - 0.678 s)

Comment: Can you see much time does client creation takes? You  could use thread local cache to store the client and reuse it every time instead of attempting to create a new one.

Comment: @apatniv client creations takes 0.01 s. As I know client send POST requests to InfluxDB to write points.

Comment: @apatniv I don't know why but when I use thread_local client not all points is written. So I pushed all futures to vec and executed it. Now it takes 4 s instead of 6 s.

Comment: https://www.influxdata.com/blog/optimizing-influxdb-performance-for-high-velocity-data/ and https://v2.docs.influxdata.com/v2.0/write-data/best-practices/optimize-writes/

Comment: You may use UDP transport with "InfluxDB line protocol". This can be useful in some cases. Configure InfluxDB to use numeric time format with minimal precision. For example, you may set `precision="ms"` in `[[udp]]` section of the influxdb.conf. Do not use multiple threads if you don't understand how the CPU caches works. You will not get a speed gain if your data will often run from the cache of one CPU to the cache of another (including data inside influxdb). Do not use many thread writers if you have a database on one hdd (or ssd).